# How to implement TCP/IP responder "service" in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I have the following architecture for a project I'm working on.

[image: Architecture Drawing]

My question is how to begin implementing the TCP/IP responder part.
It's function, in case the diagram is hard to read, is to wait for a connection from the Order Viewing client, and subsequently notify said client of incoming orders.

I was thinking a queue, but unfortunately I don't know where something like this would fit in the VS2008 hierarchy of things.

If it's part of the ASP.NET web page, should I use the application start event to start the TCP IP responder?

It's not a web service, because those respond to http requests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to implement your "TCP responder" I'd probably implement it as a windows service and have both the ASP.NET app and the Winform client contact it (e.g. to avoid the problem of recycling of the ASP.NET etc.)

That said, I can think of gazillion easier ways to get the effect you want to achieve (getting the winform client to know about new orders) such as

- Using Queues as you mentioned. Windows comes with MSMQ (you need to enable it in add windows features). Using MSMQ from C# [is fairly easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx). You can also [use WCF if you like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx)
- exposing an [http endpoint on the client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395208%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and have the client notify the ASP.NET server where it is listening by calling one of its pages
- write the orders to the DB and poll it from the client/use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency to know when there's a change

Heck even writing the orders to a file on a shared folder with a FileSystemWatcher would work (though I'd probably wouldn't recommend that)

Comment: +1 for WCF suggestion.  The WCF service can handle both a NET TCP binding and an HTTP bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use http? You already have the http server so you don't need any TCP responder - just do http polling at the client.
And if you don't want polling or have too many clients then you can use something like SignalR for notifications.

Comment: The point is to avoid http polling. Haven't heard of SignalR, will check it out.